# Which theme is used in reveal.js for code blocks?

Tags: themes, reveal.js

Which theme is used in reveal.js by default for highlight syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default theme is Zenburn, see [index.html](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/00b9c2b929dd46303696326c9b4bcbf3362578ac/index.html#L13).

Also try Zenburn here: http://softwaremaniacs.org/media/soft/highlight/test.html